# Remote Server Authentication to SharePoint Online using SharePointOnlineCredentials

Tags: .net, authentication, sharepoint, dll, office365

I am trying to programmatically authenticate to my SharePoint Online 2013 (like Office 365) site from a remote Windows server.  I've tried various methods, but the most promising is using the "Client Object Model" SharePointOnlineCredentials.  It works fine on my dev PC, but fails ("FileNotFoundException: msoidcliL.dll") when I deploy to my server.

- I am using this method:
  http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/01/authenticating-net-client-object-model.html
- On my dev PC, I've installed SharePoint 2013 client object model
  assemblies from
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585; which
  work fine on my PC
- In Visual Studio, I've referenced
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and the
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll (C:\Program Files\Common
  Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Client)
- In Visual Studio, I am NOT able to add a reference for msoidcliL.dll (even
  though it is on my PC in the "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft
  shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI" folder).
- I have all 3 files
  of these files in my bin folder on the server:  msoidcliL.dll, 
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll, and
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
- My server is a shared/virtual server and does not have SharePoint installed.

How can I get SharePointOnlineCredentials to work on my server?

My c# code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://mysite.sharepoint.com/"))
        {
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "mypassword".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("myusername@mysite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Lbl1.Text = web.Title;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just watched a presentation about exactly your problem, you should watch the blog of Peter Holpar (http://pholpar.wordpress.com/) as he wanted to post the code soon. He was using SharePointOnlineCredentials using a Windows 8 app.

Comment: A possible cause of the issue is described here:  http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2013/03/18/sharepointonlinecredentials-and-msoidclil-dll-file-not-found-exception/ -- a  reference to a ClentUtility SetupDirectory that is hard-coded in the registry.  I am not aware of a way to edit the registry on my shared server and I can't install the Client Components SDK there.